# Can't get image links to appear in a horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm trying to add a row of bookmarks to my custom homepage. After following [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp) as well as troubleshooting with other stackoverflow posts, I can't get these image links to line up horizontally. This is the HTML I'm using to make it horizontal.

```
<h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
                        <img src="/home/henry/Documents/FFH/Assets/atlas.svg" style="width:100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
                        <img src="/home/henry/Documents/FFH/Assets/envelope.svg" style="width:100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
                        <img src="/home/henry/Documents/FFH/Assets/play.svg" style="width:100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
                        <img src="/home/henry/Documents/FFH/Assets/book.svg" style="width:100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://www.bankofamerica.com/">
                        <img src="/home/henry/Documents/FFH/Assets/dollar-sign.svg" style="width:100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h3>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
```

[here's a link to a fiddle of the site](http://jsfiddle.net/duf59ats/). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: please add the corresponding HTML lines aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vanishingly few good reasons to use float. This would be much easier with flex or grid.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

/*
  the rest of the css is purely for costmetic or illustrative
  purposes and is not necessary to achieve the layout
*/
.grid {
  gap: 8px;
}

.container > * {
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<h3>Using flex:</h3>
<div class="container flex">
    <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/200/200">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/201/201">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/202/202">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/199/199">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bankofamerica.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/198/198">
    </a>
</div>

<h3>Using grid:</h3>
<div class="container grid">
    <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/200/200">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/201/201">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/202/202">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/199/199">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bankofamerica.com/">
      <img src="//placekitten.com/198/198">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here. The simple quick fix is removing the `h3` tag from your code that's around the images. You have it set to a 40px width in the CSS. You could also fix the h3 CSS.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4e5461;
  border-width: 50px 20px;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  outline-style: none;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

iframe path {
  fill: #f3f4f5;
}

table,
th,
td {
  background-color: #4e5461;
  color: #4CAF50;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="globe">
</h1>
<h2>
  <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table cellpadding="0" style="color: #4e5461;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="q" size="60" style="color:#4e5461;" maxlength="255" value="">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.bankofamerica.com/">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, you don't have any text inside these divs, it's just a row of image links so you really don't need all the wrapping column divs at all. Can just use `text-align: center` on your container and list out the image links.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4e5461;
  border-width: 50px 20px;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  outline-style: none;
}

h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

iframe path {
  fill: #f3f4f5;
}

table,
th,
td {
  background-color: #4e5461;
  color: #4CAF50;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

.row a {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="globe">
</h1>
<h2>
  <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table cellpadding="0" style="color: #4e5461;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="q" size="60" style="color:#4e5461;" maxlength="255" value="">

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</h2>
<div class="row">
  <a href="https://wiki.archlinux.org/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x20">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x20">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x20">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x20">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.bankofamerica.com/">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x20">
  </a>
</div>
```